# How to dynamically generate an implementation of an interface

Tags: java, dynamic, reflection

Let's say I have an interface that provides connection properties for a server:

```
public interface ServerConfig {
    String getHostname();

    int getPort();
}
```

Is there any way to dynamically create an implementation class of said interface at runtime that would return values from some arbitrary source (application arguments, system properties, external configuration file, etc.)?

More specifically, let's say there's a `.properties` file with the following contents:

```
hostname = localhost
port = 80
```

and a method

```
ServerConfig fromFile(String filename);
```

Calling this method should return an instance of a dynamically generated implementation of `ServerConfig` that would return values from the `.properties` file specified in the `filename` argument.

Clarification:

The goal is to be able to add additional interfaces whose methods would return values specified in an external source (i.e. a `.properties` file) without manually implementing them each time. A simple solution would create implementations of interfaces that return property values that match those of the interface method name being called, i.e. calling `getHostname()` would return the value of the `hostname` property, calling `getBla()` from some other interface would look for and return the value of the `bla` property, etc.

Comment: Yes that's what an interface is, at runtime you instantiate the class you want implementing it.  I have no idea what the actual question is here, are you just asking how to use an interface?

Comment: I would like to dynamically and at runtime generate the class that implements the interface

Comment: Use polymorphism?  Write code? A factory? A switch statement?

Comment: These requirements are confusing. Please describe why you think you need this/ what your goal is.

Comment: Code is not like magic. Developers just write code. Create a concrete `public class PropertiesFileServerConfig implements ServerConfig` and return a concrete instance of it on that `fromFile()` call.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to do anything like that.
You can just write a normal class that implements the interface and takes a filename as a constructor parameter.